# backbone view not being shown when page first rendered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following set of Views and Router, when the page is first displayed the 'welcome' view navigated too in the 'initialize' method for the Router is not visible - the render method is called but the  element is not updated. If navigate to another view (hashbang) and then navigate back I can then see the initial view.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        contentView: null,

        routes: {
            'welcome': 'welcomeAction',
            'settings': 'settingsAction',
            'books': 'booksAction',
            'book/:id': 'bookAction'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.navigate('welcome', true);
        },

        welcomeAction: function () {
            this.contentView = new views.WelcomeView({ 'model': new models.Welcome() });
        },

        settingsAction: function () {
            this.contentView = new views.SettingsView({ 'model': new models.Settings() });
        },

        booksAction: function () {
            this.contentView = new views.BooksView({ 'model': new models.Books() });
        },

        bookAction: function (id) {
            this.contentView = new views.BookView({ 'model': new models.Book({ 'Id': id }) });
        }
    });

    function App() {

        this.router = null;

        this.initialize = function () {
            this.router = new AppRouter;
            Backbone.history.start();
        };
    };

    var reader = new App;
    reader.initialize();
```

The View is shown below:

```
WelcomeView: Backbone.View.extend({

        'el': '#content-pane',

        tagName: 'div',

        template: _.template(templates.welcome),

        events: {
        },

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.renderLoading();
            this.model.fetch({ success: _.bind(function () {
                this.model.set({ Date: new Date() });
                this.render();
            }, this)
            });
        },

        renderLoading: function () {
            var html = _.template(templates.loading)();
            $(this.el).empty();
            $(this.el).append(html);
        },

        render: function () {
            var html = this.template({ date: this.model.get('Date') });
            $(this.el).empty();
            $(this.el).append(html);
        }
    }),
```

Comment: Why do you have `el` and `tagName` at the same time? When you define `el` it should reference existing element and if `el` is not defined, then `tagName`, `className` and `id` properties are used to create a new one. If `#content-pane` already exists then remove `tagName` and if not then don't define it and use `tagName` and `id`

Comment: Also use `.html(html)` instead of `.empty()` and then `.append(html)`.

Comment: because i didn't know any better :) thanks for the advice...

Comment: @AkwardCoder: :) .. Let me know if any of those changes helped. If not I will try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: unfortunately not solved the problem, the 'el' is a div tag and when the user clicks on different links the contents of the div is replaced - this all works accept for when the first view is rendered when the page is initially displayed...

Comment: @AkwardCoder I tried to reproduce your problem and it worked for me :-/. Instead of model fetching I just used a `setTimeout` and changed the code a bit so JSLint won't have problems with it. Have a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/WemLV/)**. If that works for you then try to temporarily use my version of the view in your code or upload your app somewhere and give me a link :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a `$(document).ready` issue to me.  Are you sure all the content of your page (specifically `#content-pane`) is loaded before you create the view?